# How to close training window from trainNetwork in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trining my network with the following option

```
opts = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',250, ...
    'GradientThreshold',1, ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.005, ...
    'LearnRateSchedule','piecewise', ...
    'LearnRateDropPeriod',125, ...
    'LearnRateDropFactor',0.2, ...
    'Verbose',0, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');
```

On each batch it opens plot and it remains on screen. How to close it?

Also it opens these plots from within live script. How to make it embed image into script body as in Jupyter notebook?

**UPDATE**

Neither of

```
nntraintool close 

nnet.guis.closeAllViews()
```

work. It looks like this is not that window of `nntraintool`.

Comment: I do not have the toolbox so I am unable to try this myself, but the documentation states: *'Plots' — Plots to display during network training*. Try changing 'Plots' to `'none'`

Comment: Yes, but I need plots :) I just want them to close when finished.

Comment: I see, perhaps you could use `OutputFcn` and close the plots when `State` is `done` ? Does `close all` not close them?

Comment: @pkpkpk `close all` also doesn't help

Comment: Is solution found or not?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is

```
nnet.trainParam.showWindow = 0
```